# ¿para qué es necesario este paréntesis en el destructuring?

Tags: javascript, poo, objeto, javascript-objeto

¿Por qué es necesario el paréntesis al asignar valores mediante destructuring de un objeto de la manera mostrada abajo? ¿qué función cumple? ¿Por qué no funciona como lo hace cuando se usa destructuring de arrays? Gracias de antemano.

```
//sin paréntesis:
let a, b;
{ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 };
console.log(a, b); //muestra error


//con paréntesis:
let a, b;
({ a, b } = { a: 10, b: 20 }); //qué función cumple este paréntesis?
console.log(a, b); //muestra 10 y 20.


//destructuring de array sin paréntesis:
let a, b;
[a, b] = [10, 20];
console.log(a, b); //muestra 10 y 20.
```

Comment: [Documentación MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#desestructuraci%C3%B3n_de_objetos): *...no es una sintaxis independiente válida, debido a que {a, b} en el lado izquierdo se considera un bloque y no un objeto literal.*

Comment: @aeportugal pero qué hace el paréntesis para que luego sí se vuelva una sintaxis válida? por qué siendo un array sí que el bloque izquierdo es considerado lo que es (un array)? los paréntesis operan, por norma de JS, de alguna manera bajo este contexto? me es difícil explicar mi duda. Espero la comprendas.